# Using rsync to synchronise folders without overwriting files of same name on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, backup, terminal, rsync

I would like to synchronise the contents of two directories.

- Without overwriting but to create a copy if two files have the same name, but different sizes
- Without duplicating if two files have the same name and size.
- To work recursively

So far I have found the following command which might work

```
 $ rsync -varE --progress ~/folder /volumes/server/folder
```

But I'm not entirely sure what the `-E` flag does. It was suggested by a user on bananica.com but couldn't see a description for it in the manual. Would this do what I require successfully?

Comment: From the manual page of `rsync`: -E, --executability preserve executability

Comment: There's an interesting approach to use rsync to build similar functionality to Apples Time Machine. I have never used it, but maybe this is for you: http://blog.interlinked.org/tutorials/rsync_time_machine.html

Comment: Can you be specific as to why these rules are so. e.g. by 'having the same name and size' do you consider this as a test of whether the files are the same? And by 'same name but different size' does this refer to files that have changed?

Comment: Same name, same size = files are identical; same name but different size = files have changed. Sometimes copying a folder without overwriting will create duplicates of identical files which I won't want. Note, I'm doing this on a mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

-E actually preserves extended attributes on OS X, but -a (--archive) implies -p (--perms) which implies --executability.

-b (--backup) adds a tilde to the end of files that would normally get overwritten:

```
rsync -ab ~/folder /Volumes/server/
```

`-b --suffix _old` would rename file.txt to file.txt_old

rsync compares both file sizes and modification times by default. --size-only only compares sizes. -c compares checksums, but it's slower.